# MVVM: Change button content and command binding at runtime

Tags: wpf, mvvm, commandbinding

I have a button which should be used as Connect or Disconnect button, depending on the Connected-property of the ViewModel:

```
<Button Content="_Connect" x:Name="connectButton" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>
```

Now depending on the property, the content should be either "_Connect" or "_Disconnect" and the command binding should go either to ConnectCommand or DisconnectCommand.

Is there a nice way of doing that or should I use a command for both and have a DataTrigger to set the content separately depending on the Connected property?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you have a DataTrigger, it could also set the Command Binding.

Comment: "command for both and have a DataTrigger to set the content separately depending on the Connected property" is good, alternatively you can bind Content to Connected and use ValueConverter.

Comment: @Clemens: I am ashamed to admit: It was that easy.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed very simple:

As Clemens suggested, I ended up setting the Binding and the Contents with a DataTrigger.

Answer (score 1):

Using same command you can handle this with enum.

```
   <Button Name="btnOption"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Grid.Column="8"
        Command="{Binding RxOptionCommand}"
        Content="{Binding RxOptionContent}" />
```

***Based on your View Model's connect or disconnect business change the button content and at the same time set your enum value in to a variable.***

```
 public enum EnumRxRecStatus
    {
        None = 0,
        New = 1,
    }
```

Now you can check the condition in to your command event

```
public void OnRxOptionCommand(object sender)
        {
             if (RequestForRxOption == EnumRxRecStatus.None) 
                {
                     // Do something
                }

            else if (RequestForRxOption == EnumRxRecStatus.New) 
                {
                   // Do something
                }           
        }
```